# Multiple wildcards in single elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to get some results from elasticsearch using the below query. But it gives no result. I have data which should come in the result. If i run any of the mentioned wildcard then it gives result but together it gives no result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
              "firstname": "*nne*"
            }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastname": "*ste*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It should return something like `Anne rooster` for example. Anyone knows if we can use multiple wildcards using AND operator? If there are any example that will be helpful. I have tried query_string as well but again with no result.

Comment: You can try using the "keyword" analyzer for the fields in your query to see if that makes a difference

"wildcard": {
              "firstname.keyword": "*nne*"
            }

Comment: @Gaya3Govindaraj it works for single field like for firstname but when I add multiple fields then it doesn't work.